# Tableauで3項目以上の最大値を出すには？

Tags: tableau

Tableauでデータ分析をしています。
Excelのように、MAX関数を用いて、
複数項目（3項目以上）の中から最大値を出したいです。

ところが、TableauのMAX関数は、
2項目までしか指定できませんでした…

良い方法は無いでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ワークアラウンドとして、`max(max(max(a, b), c), d)` みたくネストすることで達成できます。

ただこれは面倒ですし可読性が落ちます。任意個の引数に対して `max()` できるようにする機能要求投票がフォーラムに出ていますが、未実装のようです。

- [MIN( expr1, expr2, ... expr_n )](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/3405)